# .Net Core Identity Password does not recognize Turkish Characters as UpperCase or LowerCase

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I defined a class called TurkishIdentityErrorDescriber which inherited from Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity IdentityErrorDescriber to translate Identity error descriptions to Turkish language. When I try to register userManager's CreateAsync with a password include turkish upper case letters "ÇÇÇÇÇÇ1" password, it returns PasswordRequiresLower and PasswordRequiresUpper IdentityError. How can I define turkish characters to identity password without getting an error?

Here is my Identity Error Describer Class

```
   public class TurkishIdentityErrorDescriber : IdentityErrorDescriber
    {
        public override IdentityError DefaultError() { return new IdentityError { Code = nameof(DefaultError), Description = $"Some turkish error definitions bla bla bla." }; }
        public override IdentityError PasswordRequiresLower() { return new IdentityError { Code = nameof(PasswordRequiresLower), Description = "Some turkish error definitions bla bla bla." }; }
        public override IdentityError PasswordRequiresUpper() { return new IdentityError { Code = nameof(PasswordRequiresUpper), Description = "Some turkish error definitions bla bla bla." }; }
                .
                .
                .
                .
    }
```

I get IdentityErrors from this CreateAsync method when use "ÇÇÇÇÇÇ1" as Input.Password.

```
IdentityResult result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);
```

Here is my startup.cs

```
            services.AddIdentity<User, Role>(options =>
            {
                options.Stores.MaxLengthForKeys = 128;
                options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
            })
            .AddRoles<Role>()
            .AddRoleManager<RoleManager<Role>>()
            .AddErrorDescriber<TurkishIdentityErrorDescriber>()
```

Solving Edit:

Solution is overriding PasswordValidator class.(dont't forget to add it startup.cs) Here is my class

```
    public class TurkishIdentityPasswordValidator : PasswordValidator<User>
    {

        /// <summary>
        ///     Returns true if the character is between 'a' and 'z' plus turkish characters
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="c"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public override bool IsLower(char c)
        {
            if (c == 'ğ' || c == 'ü' || c == 'ş' || c == 'ı' || c == 'ş' || c == 'ö' || c == 'ç')
                return true;
            else if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///     Returns true if the character is between 'A' and 'Z' plus turkish characters
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="c"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public override bool IsUpper(char c)
        {
            if (c == 'Ğ' || c == 'Ü' || c == 'Ş' || c == 'İ' || c == 'Ş' || c == 'Ö' || c == 'Ç')
                return true;
            else if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }

    }
```

Comment: You will have to override `PasswordValidator.IsUpper()` and `IsLower()?. The default implementation recognizes only A-Z and a-z, see [source](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetIdentity/blob/main/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/PasswordValidator.cs)

Comment: Thanks  Klaus Gütter, I overrided the PasswordValidator class, now it is working

Comment: You may add this as answer yourself